# How to print the interfaces given a mac?

Tags: bash, ifconfig

Is there a command to print the interface name given a mac or should I parse it ? if so is there a reliable way to do it ?

```
basename -a $(ls /sys/devices/**/net/* -d)

ifconfig   | cut -c 1-8 | sort | uniq -u
```

does not seem to be reliable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing `ifconfig` output is always an iffy proposition (because `ifconfig` is designed to produce human-readable output, rather than machine-readable output).

The best source of information is going to be the `/sys/class/net/<device>/address` files.  E.g:

```
$ cat /sys/class/net/wlp3s0/address 
3c:a9:f4:5a:8b:24
```

To work backwards from a MAC address to an interface name, you could do something like:

```
$ grep -l 3c:a9:f4:5a:8b:24 /sys/class/net/*/address
/sys/class/net/wlp3s0/address
```

...and then get the interface name from that path.

Comment: grep -l 07:00:27:ad:66:4c /sys/class/net/*/address | awk -F'/' '{print $5}'